# Test chain 48 hours constant

Tags: protocol, sandbox

Why are the 48 hours of test chain completely hard-coded ?
https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/blob/master/src/proto_alpha/lib_protocol/src/amendment.ml#L88-89

I mean as opposed to coming from e.g. bootstrap-parameters like time-between-blocks and so on.

I guess “parametrizing” this would be a protocol update even if the value remains the exact same 48h.

Comment: I am not sure of what you are asking, or what you are expecting as a reply. Yes, it is bad to put constants in code, yes, it could have been a parameter, yet, when you want to launch the network fast, you postpone such changes to later... Anyway, such a constant cannot be changed without a protocol amendment, so you will also need a protocol amendment to make it a parameter...